# AngularJS : Restangular Library

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

I am experimenting with the fabulous Restangular library, and I have run into some trouble when trying to return some JSON objects and bind them to the $scope object.

I have this function inside my Factory script, which essentially is just returning a list of blogs utilising the Restangular.getList() function.

```
angular.module("ecmaworld").factory("Authenticate", function(Restangular) {
// Testing Function
var Blogs = Restangular.all("blogs");
return {
    blogs: function() {
        Blogs.getList("blogs").then(function(blogs) {
            return blogs;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
};});
```

The Factory method here returns the a list of blog posts. I then attempt to call this function which I ahve defined in the Factory script and utilise it in one of my controller scripts like this:

```
angular.module("ecmaworld").controller("LoginController", function($scope, Authenticate) {

//Testing function
$scope.getBlogs = function() {
    $scope.blogs = Authenticate.blogs();
};
});
```

When I attempt to use the "data-ng-repeat" directive to loop through all the blogs posts, I do not get anything displaying. I can see that teh API method has worked through google developers as the http response returns the JSON objects. However, I am unsure to why they are not displaying when attempting to loop through them in the VIEW. If you could please assist me, that would be much appreciated. I am only new to Angular, so go easy guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blogs()` method needs to return the promise...

```
blogs: function() {
    return Blogs.getList("blogs").then(function(blogs) {
        return blogs;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And then assign the result to the scope property when the promise is resolved...

```
$scope.getBlogs = function() {
    Authenticate.blogs().then(function (blogs) {
        $scope.blogs = blogs;
    });
};
```

Comment: Excellent! This has worked for me now. It completely slipped my mind that I was not returning anything. Could you please explain to me what the 'promise' exactly is?